# Api Youtube Upload with Service Account

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube

I want to upload a video from server to youtube.
I create a service account to auth,

```
var path = "720_final.mov"
// var key =  readJson(`${__dirname}/secret.json`);
var google = require('googleapis');
var youTube = google.youtube('v3');
var authClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    "xxxx@yyyyyyy.gserviceaccount.com",
    "secret.p12",
    null,
   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'],
   null
 );
authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       return;
    }
    authClient.setCredentials(tokens);
    var req = Youtube.videos.insert({
        auth: authClient,
        resource: {
            // Video title and description
            snippet: {
                title: "Testing YoutTube API NodeJS module"
              , description: "Test video upload via YouTube API"
            }
            // I don't want to spam my subscribers
          , status: {
                privacyStatus: "public"
            }
        }
        // This is for the callback function
      , part: "snippet,status"

        // Create the readable stream to upload the video
      , media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(path)
        }
    }, (err, data) => {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data)
        process.exit();
    });
```

My file `720_final.mov` has size 33Mb.
When upload to 34.6Mb seem like Upload cannot find channel of user to upload ??

[image]

However, when is use tokens generator from Oauth2, upload success, example use oath 2 https://github.com/IonicaBizau/youtube-api/blob/master/example/index.js

Anyone can give me a resolve or a keyword to fix this?

Comment: Have you follow this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service_accounts